# Time field e.g. "14:24:05" - show only "14:24" without seconds

Tags: sql, db2

I have a time field in db2 named "chgtime" in library "flow", table "changes"

How can I convert this time field, that it only shows me the hour and minute like "14:25" or with text only the hour like "the hour was 14".

For example, if time in one row is e.g. "14:24:05" the output in query should be like "14:25".

For following statement I get only null for all values in chgtime

**select varchar_format(varchar(chgtime), 'hh24') as hour_minute from flow.changes**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select VARCHAR_FORMAT (TIMESTAMP (CURRENT DATE) + MIDNIGHT_SECONDS (chgtime) SECONDS, 'HH24:MI')
from flow.changes
```

Comment: Thank you very much, as always you're a great person!